# Convert json array of objects to bash associative array

Tags: bash, jq

I have an array of json objects that I'd like to convert to an associative array in bash with a slight alteration to the key

```
{
"Parameters": [
    {
        "Name": "/path/user_management/api_key",
        "Type": "SecureString",
        "Value": "1234",
        "Version": 1
    },
    {
        "Name": "/path/user_management/api_secret",
        "Type": "SecureString",
        "Value": "5678",
        "Version": 1
    }
]
}
```

I know I need to use jq and sed but I just can't quite find the proper combination of doing what I'm looking for.   Need to strip out "/path/user_management/" and set the remaining as the key, and use Value for value.

Trying to find a fairly clean one liner piping commands together.  What I'd like to end up with is a bash associative array of something like:

```
myArray[api_key]="1234"
myArray[api_secret]="5678"
```

Comment: It certainly does on my linux environment so I accepted the answer.  Doesn't work on my mac, so I'll have to work through that.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: see also [JSON array to bash variables using jq](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413878/json-array-to-bash-variables-using-jq)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asking for a one-liner code is as good as asking for unreadable code. If you want do this in a proper way, read the output of `jq` command in a while loop and strip out unwanted characters as required.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# declare an associative array, the -A defines the array of this type
declare -A _my_Array

# The output of jq is separated by '|' so that we have a valid delimiter
# to read our keys and values. The read command processes one line at a 
# time and puts the values in the variables 'key' and 'value'
while IFS='|' read -r key value; do
    # Strip out the text until the last occurrence of '/' 
    strippedKey="${key##*/}"
    # Putting the key/value pair in the array
    _my_Array["$strippedKey"]="$value"
done< <(jq -r '.Parameters[] | "\(.Name)|\(.Value)"' json)

# Print the array using the '-p' or do one by one
declare -p _my_Array
```

Or print the array, the traditional way

```
for key in "${!_my_Array[@]}"; do 
    printf '%s %s\n' "${key}" "${_my_Array[$key]}"
done
```

Comment: Why do the opening parentheses in the last jq filter have to be escaped but not the closing ones?

Comment: @stefanct: it is string interpolation - https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#string-interpolation allowing you to run filters within double quotes, causing the filter outputs to be treated as strings